# Как сбросить массив в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив. Он заполняется данными циклом `for` копируя элементы и создавая из себя новый массив c размерами: `+` "кол-во операций".

```
int [] newAnswerTimeArray = new int[o + 1];
for (int h = 0; h < o; h++){
 newAnswerTimeArray[h] = answerTimeArray[h];
 newAnswerTimeArray[o] = queryAnswerTime;
}
```

После чего выполняется с ним нужные действия. Мне нужно очистить именно `answerTimeArray` массив, сделав в нём всего 1 ячейку `0`. То есть: `arr = new arr[1];` без элементов `java.util` и других библиотек.

Попробовал:

```
int[] delAnswerTimeArray = new int[1];
        answerTimeArray = delAnswerTimeArray;
```

Но безуспешно.

Comment: null вы не сделаете, потому что у вас тип int. Там всегда будет 0 по умолчанию.

Comment: @aleshka-batman
Ну, хотя-бы 0, он потом заменится данными.
Проблема в том, что к моменту, когда мне нужно использовать его же, у него уже около 1000 элементов. И нужно их стереть + оставить только 1 элемент с значением 0. Через `for` мне кажется - будет слишком затратно по ресурсам.

Comment: @ЮрийИва если Вам нужен массив, в котором можно добавлять и удалять элементы, то используйте `ArrayList`. Он как раз для этого и придуман.

Comment: @notaProgrammer он же написал, что без java.util(непонятно почему)

Comment: @АнтонСорокин я думаю автор не совсем понимает, что коллекциями можно и нужно пользоваться.

Comment: А чем вызван отказ от Java util?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, у вас был массив определенной длины, которую вы хотите сократить. <strike>Почему бы вам не использовать коллекции</strike> Вы можете переопределить массив.

Например,

```
int[] array = new int[15];
array[0] = 1;
...
array = new int[1];
array[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Только если в других участках кода нет иных ссылок на этот же массив.

Answer (score 3):

Размер массива изменять нельзя. Вам остаётся только завести переменную, хранящую номер ячейки массива, данные до которой считаются актуальными, а после нет.